# How do I debug print an MPSGraph from Apple Performance Shaders

Tags: objective-c, metal

I have an `MPSGraph* graph` and I would like to print it to see the graph as built in MPS. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is an undocumented `dump` method that will work:

```
[graph dump];
```

It will produce output that looks like:

```
module  {
  func @main() {
    %0 = "mps.placeholder"() : () -> tensor<3x1xf32>
    %1 = "mps.placeholder"() : () -> tensor<1xi32>
    %2 = "mps.placeholder"() : () -> tensor<1xi32>
    %3 = "mps.placeholder"() : () -> tensor<1xi32>
    %4 = "mps.constant"() {value = dense<[3, 1]> : tensor<2xi32>} : () -> tensor<2xi32>
    %5 = "mps.constant"() {value = dense<-1> : tensor<i32>} : () -> tensor<i32>
    %6 = "mps.get_coordinates"(%4, %5) : (tensor<2xi32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<3x1xi32>
    %7 = "mps.multiply"(%6, %3) : (tensor<3x1xi32>, tensor<1xi32>) -> tensor<3x1xi32>
    %8 = "mps.constant"() {value = dense<-2> : tensor<i32>} : () -> tensor<i32>
    %9 = "mps.get_coordinates"(%4, %8) : (tensor<2xi32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<3x1xi32>
    %10 = "mps.multiply"(%9, %2) : (tensor<3x1xi32>, tensor<1xi32>) -> tensor<3x1xi32>
    %11 = "mps.add"(%10, %7) : (tensor<3x1xi32>, tensor<3x1xi32>) -> tensor<3x1xi32>
    %12 = "mps.add"(%11, %1) : (tensor<3x1xi32>, tensor<1xi32>) -> tensor<3x1xi32>
    %13 = "mps.constant"() {value = dense<-1> : tensor<1xi32>} : () -> tensor<1xi32>
    %14 = "mps.reshape"(%0, %13) : (tensor<3x1xf32>, tensor<1xi32>) -> tensor<3xf32>
    %15 = "mps.constant"() {value = dense<-1> : tensor<1xi32>} : () -> tensor<1xi32>
    %16 = "mps.reshape"(%12, %15) : (tensor<3x1xi32>, tensor<1xi32>) -> tensor<3xi32>
    %17 = "mps.constant"() {value = dense<0> : tensor<i32>} : () -> tensor<i32>
    %18 = "mps.gather"(%14, %16, %17) {batch_dims = 0 : ui32} : (tensor<3xf32>, tensor<3xi32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<3xf32>
    %19 = "mps.reshape"(%18, %4) : (tensor<3xf32>, tensor<2xi32>) -> tensor<3x1xf32>
  }
}
```

Comment: "graph" is  "MPSGraph* graph"
ref: https://dev-discuss.pytorch.org/t/a-small-mps-debugging-story/769